# Books for chess traps

Tags: opening, books, opening-traps

I have seen (and studied) some books on opening theory. They basically deal with chess openings and various lines in which those openings can transform into. But I haven't found a book which completely focuses on opening chess traps. I want to learn chess traps which originate from various openings. I have looked online and found traps like "Legal trap", "Fishing pole trap", etc. Can someone recommend me a book or even some other online material(s) which basically have a compilation of such kind of traps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chess.com has a review of [700 Opening Traps by Bill Wall](https://www.chess.com/download/view/700-opening-traps-by-bill-wall):

> Bill Wall is a well known chess writer and his book '700 opening traps' is available as a free download from the website mentioned above, as well as his many other books and articles.

The book is available for download at [http://billwall.phpwebhosting.com/](http://billwall.phpwebhosting.com/permanent/700_Opening_Traps.pdf) (this opens the book as a PDF).

Answer (score 2):

Pandolfini wrote at least one book titled "Chess Openings,  Traps and Zaps". In addition, there are numerous books of miniatures, which are, in some cases, traps.

Answer (score 1):

The Greatest Ever Chess Tricks and Traps Gary Lane. The blurb on the back says"There is no easier way to win a game of chess than by luring your opponent into a devious trap. Similarly, there's nothing worse than being the one on the receiving end. Tricks, traps and swindles lie in wait everywhere, especially so in the opening phase of the game, and many battles can be won or saved simply through learning and mastering the most important ones. In this instructive and fun book, Gary Lane looks back through chess history and at modern times to create a list of his own favourite tricks and traps. Selecting from hundreds of contenders, Lane examines a variety of factors in order to decide which ideas are most worthy of inclusion. Discover the stories behind the most cunning tricks and traps of all time; how you can utilize them to score easy wins; and how you can avoid being tricked yourself. This is an entertaining guide to the best ever tricks and traps. It offers invaluable advice from a seasoned tournament player and is ideal for players of all levels."

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Taming Wild Chess Openings](https://www.newinchess.com/Taming_Wild_Chess_Openings-p-9014.html), written by IM Watson and FM Schiller, is interesting for you. The book contains a collection of tricky openings and the authors show how to react and, if possible, refute them.

Answer (score 0):

There is even more . You can go to chessmaniac.com and there is an option of Mini Games at the left corner where you can see a lot of Tactical miniatures which consists of various Chess openings . Link of the Website is below .

[Chessmaniac Mini games](http://www.chessmaniac.com/Games/MyChessViewer/Trappy.htm)

Even you can go across the You tube Videos of Kevin from Chess Website and Gunjan Chess Videos by the name " Dirty Chess tricks " where you can learn a lot of miniatures .Hope it helps.